# CakePHP: Error Upload

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm not knowing to use image upload, and two message are showing

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Photo [APP\Controller\PhotosController.php, line 11]
Notice (8): Undefined index: uploadImg [APP\Model\Photo.php, line 38]
```

I'll post my MVC, my Model Photo:

public $name = "Photo";

```
public $validate = array(
        'uploadImg' => array(
                'uploadError' => array(
                    'rule' => 'uploadError',
                    'message' => 'Fail.',
                    'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ),
                'mineType' => array(
                    'rule' => array('mineType',array('image/gif','image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg')),
                    'message' => 'JUST (GIF,PNG e JPG).',
                    'allowEmpty' =>TRUE,
                ),
                'fileSize' => array(
                        'rule' => array(
                            'fileSize', '<=', '1MB'
                        ),
                        'message' => 'Photos < 1MB',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE
                    ),
                'processCoverUpload' => array(
                        'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
                        'message' => 'Cover Image Upload'
                    ),
            ),
    );

public function processCoverUpload($check = array()){
    if(!is_uploaded_file($check['uploadImg']['tmp_name'])){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($check['uploadImg']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROT.'img'.DS.'uploads'.DS.$check['uploadImg']['name'])){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->data[$this->alias]['uploadImg'] = 'uploads'.DS.$check['uploads']['name'];
        return TRUE;
}
```

My PhotosController:

```
public function add(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Photo->create();
            $data = $this->request->data['Photo'];
            $this->Photo->processCoverUpload();
            //debug($this->request);
            if(!$data['uploadImg']['name']){
                unset($data['uploadImg']);
            }

            if($this->Photo->save($data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Imagem salva'));                
                return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Não conseguimos salvar'));
            }
        }       
    }
```

View:

```
<?php  print $this->Form->create('Photo', array('action'=>'add', 'type' => 'file'));  ?>
    <fieldset>      
        <legend>Upload</legend>
        <?php print $this->Form->input('Image:', array('type' => 'file', 'name' => 'uploadImg')); ?>        
    </fieldset>
        <?php print $this->Form->end(_("Save")); ?>
```

I don't know if i'm right, but i call method "processCoverUpload()" that way and i didn't pass any parameter, its right?

Answer (score 0):

Your are not passing uploaded data to function which have no access without a parameter to that variable. Try

```
$data = $this->request->data['Photo'];
$this->Photo->processCoverUpload($data);
```

or

```
$this->Photo->processCoverUpload($this->request->data['Photo']);
```

Comment: Ok, i do it ", but the image didn't show inside folder! My move_upload is right?

Comment: Yea your move_uploaded_file looks correct, you may want to pr( WWW_ROT.'img'.DS.'uploads'.DS.$check['uploadImg']['name']); die() this to check if folder is correct for start you can set it like: 'c:/'.$check['uploadImg']['name']; and then fix it for directory you want

Comment: I put die(); inside my first clause in !is_uploaded_file, i guess that's problem right?

Comment: Well basicly die() terminates current script so this maybe causing you problems, Comment out all die() and check for is uploaded file and check if it works

Comment: ok, but I still can not solve! I'm trying to test if $check contains an image!

Comment: 'form' => array(
   'uploadImg' => array(
    'name' => '1503852_509064475876526_1876445108_n.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'tmp_name' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\xamp\tmp\php5AA.tmp',
    'error' => (int) 0,
    'size' => (int) 8411
   )
  )

Answer (score 0):

change uploadImg to Image in everywhere like that $data['Image']['name']; and also change $this->request->data['Photo']['Image'];

Hope it will work!